# Hippo CMS Component (Spring managed) in a catalog (Howto use a spring managed catalog component)

Tags: java, spring, hippocms

I am having problems setting up Spring in Hippo CMS in combination with a catalog.

I had a catalog configured with a **componentclassname:ServiceLinkListComponent** so I could drag & drop the component into a placeholder on a page in the channel manager.

After following the example at http://svn.onehippo.org/repos/hippo/hippo-cms7/testsuite/trunk/ I added Spring support so I had to change the componentclassname to **componentclassname:SpringBridgeHstComponent**

Unfortunately I can't link any Document with the component anymore cause the **@ParametersInfo is not recognized** cause it resides within the bean in the SpringBridgeHstComponent.

***How can I use a spring managed catalog component?***

> Component Class

```
@ParametersInfo(type = ServiceLinkListComponentInfo.class)
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class ServiceLinkListComponent extends CommonComponent {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceLinkListComponent.class);

    @Autowired
    public TestService testService;

    @Override
    public void doBeforeRender(final HstRequest request, final HstResponse response) {
        super.doBeforeRender(request, response);
        final ServiceLinkListComponentInfo paramInfo = getComponentParametersInfo(request);
        final String documentPath = paramInfo.getDocument();
        log.debug("Calling EssentialsDocumentComponent for document path:  [{}]", documentPath);

        //String test = testService.test();

        setContentBeanForPath(documentPath, request, response);
        request.setAttribute(REQUEST_ATTR_PARAM_INFO, paramInfo);
    }
}
```

> Service Class

```
@Component("testService")
public class TestService {

    public String test(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

> applicationContext.xml (in resources/META-INF.hst-assembly.overrides)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy" />
</beans>
```

> Repo
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I want but I consider it a dirty workaround. Maybe some people from HippoCMS can help here.

I created another class:

```
@ParametersInfo(type = ServiceLinkListComponentInfo.class)
public class ServiceLinkListSpringHstComponent extends SpringBridgeHstComponent {}
```

This class needs to be set in the catalog (instead the SpringBridgeHstComponent). I also tried a nested class to get rid of the second file but hippo doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original writer of the bridge class. I think you already found the current limitation and a reasonable workaround. :-)

I agree that it's not so ideal with the workaround solution because you need to add as many child class of SpringBridgeHstComponent as component configurations.

Could you please file a JIRA ticket here to imporove this?
- https://issues.onehippo.com/projects/HSTTWO

By the way, I originally thought this can be improved only in the bridge class level, but it seems to require improvements in the container level (especially with relevance module (for targeting)). So, it needs more investigation with that module.